# Does supertest support 'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, supertest

I am not able to test an API which accepts the plain text as a input. My Api is working fine with postman. Now I want to write unit test case for the same. The API always receives the text as a object. And funny thing is when I use `.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')` the API doesn't receive anything. Stange!!!

This is my testcase code :

```
const mystring = 'kashdjkasddavsdnbmavdjshgdjsagdj';
 it('/myservice/v1/api/user(POST) should return user', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/myservice/v1/api/user')
      .set({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Length': '1956',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
      })
      .send(mystring)
      .expect(201)
      .expect('user created successfully.');
  });
```

What I receive at server side

```
{kashdjkasddavsdnbmavdjshgdjsagdj}
```

What I expect at server side 
`"kashdjkasddavsdnbmavdjshgdjsagdj"` - A plain string.

`mystring` is just for reference actual content are different.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Text body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions) of `bodyParser` module. Here is an minimal working example:

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.post('/myservice/v1/api/user', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(201).send('user created successfully.');
});

module.exports = app;
```

`server.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('./server');

describe('59068158', () => {
  const mystring = 'kashdjkasddavsdnbmavdjshgdjsagdj';

  it('/myservice/v1/api/user(POST) should return user', (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post('/myservice/v1/api/user')
      .set({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        Accept: '*/*',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(mystring),
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      })
      .send(mystring)
      .expect(201)
      .expect('user created successfully.', done);
  });
});
```

Integration test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59068158/server.test.js (12.724s)
  59068158
    ✓ /myservice/v1/api/user(POST) should return user (88ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59068158/server.js:7
    kashdjkasddavsdnbmavdjshgdjsagdj

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.151s
```

As you can see, you can get the value of `mystring` sent from client using `req.body`.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59068158

Comment: I already figured it out, but yes the body parser was missing in my case too.